# search for results with the most tags in common

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do an sql query or set of queries that will allow me to find other videos that have the same tags and order them by the most number of matches. I am using php as a server side code and mysql as my database. For this I am using 2 tables.

**video**

```
  Column    Type           Null 
     timestamp  int(11)     No       
     vid_id     varchar(32) No       
     file_name  varchar(32) No       
     uploader   varchar(55) No       
     title      varchar(30) No       
     duration   varchar(7)  No       

    Keyname Type     Unique Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation
    vid_id  BTREE    Yes    No      vid_id         94       A       
    title   FULLTEXT No     No       title              0
```

**tags**

```
 Column      Type      Null 
     id     varchar(35) No       
     vid_id varchar(35) No       
     name   varchar(15) No       

    Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation
    vid_id  BTREE   Yes      No     vid_id      0      A        
    name    FULLTEXT No      No     name        0
```

One vid_id will be supplied for the query. I really am not sure what the best way to approach this would be so any expert opinion would really be appreciated.

Comment: The same tag names are available multiple times in the tags table?

Comment: Assuming the a tag can belong to multiple videos, you should set up your database differently. Your tags should just be `id, name`, and you should have a join table with `id, vid_id, tag_id`. This will save you from having several rows of: `1,2,comedy;2,6,comedy;3,7,comedy;etc`

Comment: @Rob but a single video can probably have multiple tags.

Comment: @Rikudo, the method I'm referring to would account for a many-to-many relationship. The join table could be something like tags_videos and have `id, vid_id, tag_id`

Comment: Misunderstood your method, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a

```
SELECT vid_id, COUNT(*) as count 
   FROM tags 
   WHERE name IN('list','of','videos','tags') 
   GROUP BY vid_id
   ORDER BY count DESC
```

If you choose to employ the method in my comment above, this would be slightly more complicated.

You would need first

```
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name IN('list','of','video','tags')
```

then, using those tag ids

```
SELECT vid_id, COUNT(*) as count
   FROM tags_videos
   WHERE tag_id IN(list,of,tag,ids)
   GROUP BY vid_id
   ORDER BY count DESC
```

You could probably still do it in one query, but it would use some ugly joins, and the speed difference probably wouldn't be TOO significant.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I would need to join video to be able to get all the vid information for each match. Would I just use a left join?

Comment: Yes, you could `LEFT JOIN video ON (tags.vid_id = videos.vid_id)`, You would need to adjust the SELECT to include video.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Rob really appreciate it. I will look into modifying the structure when I have some time.

Comment: No problem, there are several benefits of the modified structure. I would have a look at database normalization and many-to-many relationships. Say you had 5,000 videos, and you decide that you want to add a description to your tags. You would need to add this description for every entry in your `video` table. This could obviously cost a lot of space if descriptions are long. In the modified structure, you could add a column `description` to the tags table, and every video would now be related to their tags' descriptions as well. Check out this page: http://r937.com/relational.html